# SOQL LIKE statement not working

Tags: soql

I have the following folders where we save the email templates:

Tenders 2021
Tenders 2022
Tenders 2023

I want to run a soql query to fetch all the email templates that are stored in the folders above. I wrote the following queries but both queries return 0 records.

```
SELECT Id, Name, Subject FROM EmailTemplate WHERE FolderName LIKE '%Tender'

SELECT Id, Name, Subject FROM EmailTemplate WHERE FolderName LIKE 'Tender%'
```

I am not sure why the LIKE statement doesn't work.

Answer (score 1):

the following query worked for me

> SELECT Id, Name, Subject, Folder.Name, FolderId FROM EmailTemplate
> WHERE Folder.Name like 'Tender%'